# How to fix internet explorer column widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a project for my school where the courses, teachers and clasroomnumbers are appearing for the signage TV's.

The start of the project was made by the company who make's our software. The only thing I can do now is change some things with javascript. These changes are working fine in Chrome and Firefox. However I need it to work in Internet Explorer.

You could go to this link to see what happens:
https://www.miras.be/lokaal_bezetting_lijst/57/2019-09-26/08:00/22:00/

- When you open in Chome or Firefox it works perfectly
- When you open in IE, you see that the hours are not well displayed.

--> Strange manual solutions: When I refresh the page or do something that resizes the window, it does work.

Bad view:
[image]

Good view:
[image]

Does anyone know a javascript/jquery solution for this? 
Thanks in advance! 
Laurent

Comment: Can't you just style a min-width to make sure it's never smaller than what you want?
Some code might help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].  Also, please read [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I try to visit the the site in IE and it looks similar as it looks in any other browser. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/j2NxyQJP/167.png It is better if you post any sample HTML and CSS code which can produce the issue in IE. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering and helping! One of the problems is that I cannot make edits directly to the html or css. I do have access to a js file and edits are made like that. I now tried a fixed width on the first, fifth and sixt column. Works great in Chrome, but not in IE. I've added:


window.onload = function() {
 console.log( "ready!" ); 
 $("td:nth-child(6)").each(function(){
  $(this).css('width','100px');

 }); 
 $("td:nth-child(5)").each(function(){
  $(this).css('width','100px');

 }); 
 $("td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
  $(this).css('width','175px');
 });
};

Comment: Another strange phenomenon:
- When entering the url in IE, it shows the table wrong.
- When refreshing the page in IE, it shows the table correct.

Screen recording: https://imgur.com/a/QHeM7OC

Comment: Can you edit your ask with the code you working with tho? But also 'width' and 'min-width' aren't the same thing. But can't test anything without a sample.

Comment: Oh, just saw your answer to the answer below. Well, then, we need the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the table column width always fixed you can use
 **MIN-WIDTH** and **MAX_WIDTH** on the same column. If you will you the both property with width than table column will always same.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've added this, but however it does not have any result: 

window.onload=function(){console.log("ready!"),$("td:nth-child(6)").each(function(){$(this).css("MIN-WIDTH","100px"),$(this).css("MAX_WIDTH","100px")}),$("td:nth-child(5)").each(function(){$(this).css("MIN-WIDTH","100px"),$(this).css("MAX_WIDTH","100px")}),$("td:nth-child(4)").each(function(){$(this).css("MIN-WIDTH","100px"),$(this).css("MAX_WIDTH","100px")}),$("td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){$(this).css("MIN-WIDTH","175px"),$(this).css("MAX_WIDTH","175px")})};

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I've found the solution. As I've mentioned, it becomes ok when I resize the window. With this event at the end of my script everything was fixed. Thanks for the answers and help!

```
$(window).trigger('resize')
```